# Intellij Idea NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/util/messages/Topic

Tags: java, intellij-idea, noclassdeffounderror, java-13

I installed the newest version of [IntelliJ Idea (2019.3.1)](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=mac).
I created a new Comand Line App project (default one).
When I try to run it (by clicking a button), I get an error:

```
Error:Module 'untitled' tests: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/util/messages/Topic
```

What does this `util/messages/Topic` mean, and where do I find it?
How can I fix the problem? I tried re-installing, but it didn't help.

I'm running `macOS HS 10.13.6` and `java 13`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue may be [caused by the third-party plug-ins](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-224829#focus=streamItem-27-3740215.0-0).

See if disabling/uninstalling the non-bundled plug-ins helps.

Comment: The problem was with plugins. They were synced from the previous version of Intellij. Just updating all the plugins solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check your idea build log，maybe U can find what happend。
Help -> Show Log in Finder

I remove a thrift support plugin then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it works if you delegate building to Maven under settings -> Maven -> Running